# Chef Ruby object and collections

Tags: ruby, collections, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I've dipped my toe in chef and am having a few difficulties with what should be simple concepts.

I'm obtains data from a node by running a search; my plan is to iterate over the results and create an object of type X setting its variables as I go.

I'd like to store these objects in a collection so that I can access them later in the recipe to carry out other tasks and so on.

My GoogleFu has so far come up short and I'm worried that I'm tackling this in the wrong way.  My search is fine and returning the values, my separate class is also fine but the storing of these objects into a collection and then persisting that is proving more difficult.  Many posts frown against using arrays for my purpose(if it's possible) and I've not found anything similar to an ArrayList or Map.  Additionally, if I use a ruby collection, does it need to be maintained inside a ruby block?

Thanks for any help / advice.

Comment: It is hard to understand question you are asking, maybe you could provide the code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

With Chef, you have several ways of storing persistent data:
1) set node attributes
2) chef data bags
3) chef vault
4) environments
5) environment recipes
6) roles

IMHO, you should decide where this data should reside by determining which of the items I listed it belongs to.

What does it apply to? What does it describe?

Answer (score 1):

You got to be more specific in where you are actually facing the issue but as far as I have understood why not 
just define a ruby class and initialize all the variables you are supposed to get. In the recipe instantiate the object and keep settings its properties from the result. There should be no issue in this approach.

But more importantly what is your use-case here, because you could just define an array attribute and then keep syncing the result in that attribute .  As in ruby Objects are referenced , thus any change you make to resource attributes which takes that object, changes are persistent to in that object.